# Header location output is null after session

Tags: php

I want to redirect my page to another page with session values session have value but header is not working. When I `var_dump` header it's showing NULL. I also try by a javascript `window.location.href="";` but it's not passing session values

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome. Please post actual code, not screenshots. Also you should rephrase your question and use some formatting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ob_start top of the page.header() get working.

ob_start();